# Preloading data into JSF page before response is rendered for the previous request

Tags: jsf

I am a beginner in JSF. I am building an application where on loggin on user details from the database are to be displayed in another JSP. I use a managed bean each for all of my jsp pages (JSF) I have defined thier scope as request in my faces-config XML. On logging in the details are verified by an actionListener method in my login page. Before leaving this method I am attempting to set attributes of the managed bean of the next page. But the state that I have set is not preserved in the second page. What am I missing out.

P.S. Please redirect me if this question was asked before and answered.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary between the two requests is when you return the navigation outcome from your managed bean action. Then a redirect (if configured so) is triggered to that outcome.

You have three options:

- don't use `<redirect />` in your navigation rules - thus you'll stay within the same request even when you show another page after submit. The downside is that this hurts user experience - if refresh is pressed, the ugly 'resubmit' dialog appears
- use `session` scope - this is not harmful in small doses, but be careful not to have too many session-scoped beans.
- use a conversation framework (like [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html)) - defines a custom scope called "conversation.access" - your data is accessible as long as it is needed.
- use [`<a4j:keepAlive>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.2.GA/en/devguide/html/a4j_keepAlive.html) from richfaces - preferred for ajax-requests.

Comment: I am more likely going to explore the third option for it seems to be a solution to problems that may arise later on. Thanks and can you also tell me where the in the execution the normal request scope ends?

Comment: Thanks again. I hadn't known bout the accepting answers bit. Sorry. Have done that now.